# Filtering a column and summing values (in Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel worksheet, pieces of which are shown below:

I want to filter column D so they're unique (i.e., cat, dog, fish) and sum the values corresponding to those values like this:

[image]

[image: sheet screenshot]

I'm familiar with filtering ranges in Excel, formulas, and such functions as `COUNTIF()`, but I can't make this work.

Comment: Assuming you're on the same account - you can always edit your posts. Its a better idea, since SU isn't a forum and we do things differently here. If these accounts are seperate, get a registered one and use the contact us link for a merger. Have a look at the [help] and [tour] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Listing distinct values, and summing values depending on data in another column can be done with the formulas below.  Using your sample data, the results are shown in the following table.

[image]

To find the distinct values in column D, type this formula in G2 and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$9,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$D$2:$D$9),0,0),0)),"")
```

Note that there *MUST* be a row above the first row of data for this formula to work correctly.  I've used a row with column names here, but it could be an empty row.

To get the sum of the counts for each distinct value, type this formula in H2 and fill down:

```
 =SUMIF(D$2:D$9,G2,E$2:E$9)
```

A good explanation of how to list/count unique and distinct values can be found [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/). And some great examples using the SUMIF() function are given [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function).  I hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: This is a perfectly good, well-reasoned answer that solves the problem and includes references for further instruction.  Whoever voted this answer down, please grow some cojones and give a reason.

Comment: @Alasdair, if you found this answer helpful, please see [this help topic](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).  Thanks.