# Combine multiple rows of the same value and get total next to them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to combine several rows of the same value and get the totals next to them.

In the example below I would like to see item 604K89996 (A2) show up with the count of 23 next to it in cell B2.

```
item
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
604K89996
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
JC92-01998A
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
604K89996
```

Can this be done?

I have accomplished this part but now I am trying to pull data from another sheet into this worksheet. I suspect this is a lookup function but I am having troubles with it. Is there someone I can send the file to so they can look at it?

Comment: Follow the steps in the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1231891/filtering-a-column-and-summing-values-in-excel/1232109#1232109)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Pivot Table.

Put `Items` in both the `Rows` and the `Values`.

Make sure it is `Count of Item`.  It should default to this.  If not right click on the label under `Values` and select `Value Field Settings` and change to `Count`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set B = Range("B:B")
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    A.Copy B
    B.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, "C").Value = wf.CountIf(A, Cells(i, "B").Value)
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a formula, but it won't combine the results, rather it will show the relevant count on every row.

Assuming that your data is in cells `A2:A38`, the formula you need is `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$38, A2)`. Put this into cell `B2` and auto-fill it down to cell `B38`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I think the macro is what I was aiming for as I will need to pull from another worksheet and add columns too. This poses another obstacle for me as I have never tried using a macro...not even sure how to create one. I will do a search and work my way through it. You guys are awesome! Thank you again!