# vba/excel analysis of large data set

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am working with a large quantity of data in excel and think that VBA may be helpful. I have approximately 500 rows, column A has names in it (approximately 150). I want to apply formulas to the other columns when the names match. There are varying numbers of rows that have the same name, between 2 and 10. I'm analyzing data and want to look at it per person, including comparing values between the rows and summing values. I don't know how to do for loops without using an integer counter. Does anyone have suggestions of how to tackle this? Thank you!

example spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't need VBA. Listing or counting duplicate values is easily done with formulas in Excel.  And calculations using other columns associated with a particular name is fairly easy too.   If you clearly explain what you're trying to do, people here can point you in the right direction.  You might also check out the formulas COUNTIF(), COUNTIFS(), SUMIF() and SUMIFS() to get an idea of what can be done.

Comment: And see this example of [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1231891/filtering-a-column-and-summing-values-in-excel/1232109#1232109)

Comment: i need to find the earliest service date after admission for each name and then total the number of visits after admission (countif could work for that portion). my data set has about 150 names so i cant just do COUNTIF(A2="a",.....

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind having a list of the distinct patients in a column of their own?

This would be done with a formula, and here's what it would look like:

[image]

The formula in D2 lists the distinct patients:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$20),0,0),0)),"")
```

In F2, we count the number of service visits for each patient in the (short) list:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$20,D2,C$2:C$20,">0")
```

And finally, in E2, we find the first service date:

```
=MIN(IF((1*(D2=A$2:A$20)*(C$2:C$20))=0,"",(1*(D2=A$2:A$20)*(C$2:C$20)))
```

This one is an array formula, so it is entered with CTRL-Shift Enter, rather than just Enter.  If entered correctly, Excel will surround the formula with curly brackets {}.

After the formulas are entered, fill them down far enough to list all the patients.  This is most easily done by selecting the first cell holding the formula (D2 in this example) and then SHIFT-clicking on a cell in column F that is far enough down.  Then choose "Fill > Down" from the Edit menu.

If you guessed wrong about how far down to go, just repeat the process from the last row.

I hope this helps, let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: All: That last formula is cumbersome. I created an array of the service dates for a given patient, with zeros elsewhere.  But then I had to use the IF() to remove the zeros so the MIN() would work right.  It's ugly.  Anybody have a better idea? Hey, @Gary'sStudent. :-)

Comment: And @ScottCraner.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you might want to use the DMIN() or, if you have excel 2016, the MINIFS(). See example screenshot:

[image]

columns a-c are as your columns, I may have changed the data when I was testing the formulas myself...